# List combination based on value of each index in another list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following two lists

```
list_1 = [3, 5, 7, 2]

list_2 = [
          '1-CHA', '2-NOF', '3-INC',
          '4-CHA', '5-NOF', '6-NOF', '7-INC', '8-INC',
          '9-INC', '10-INC', '11-CHA', '12-NOF', '13-CHA', '14-CHA', '15-INC', 
          '16-INC', '17-INC'
         ]
```

I want to combine the two lists in the following way:

```
final_list = [
              '1-CHA|2-NOF|3-INC',
              '4-CHA|5-NOF|6-NOF|7-INC|8-INC',
              '9-INC|10-INC|11-CHA|12-NOF|13-CHA|14-CHA|15-INC',
              '16-INC|17-INC'
             ]
```

**final_list** - should have the same length as **list_1**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an iterator from `list_2` so that you can fetch items from the list for the number of times specified in `list_1` by calling `next` on the iterator:

```
seq = iter(list_2)
final_list = ['|'.join(next(seq) for _ in range(n)) for n in list_1]
```

You can also use `itertools.islice` instead to avoid repeated calls to `next` (thanks to @gog for the suggestion):

```
from itertools import islice
seq = iter(list_2)
final_list = ['|'.join(islice(seq, 0, n)) for n in list_1]
```

To do it without using list comprehension or generator expression, you can create an empty list and append items to it:

```
seq = iter(list_2)
final_list = []
for n in list_1:
    items = []
    for _ in range(n):
        items.append(next(seq))
    final_list.append('|'.join(items))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/BlandEssentialJavadoc

Comment: alternatively, consider `itertools.islice` for the inner part

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```py
final_list = [
    # Join with a `|` pipe character
    '|'.join(
        # Slice list 2
        list_2[
            # Start at the sum of values less than i then sum of values including i
            sum(list_1[:i]):sum(list_1[:i+1])])
    for i in range(len(list_1))
]
```

On one line:

```
final_list = ['|'.join(list_2[sum(list_1[:i]):sum(list_1[:i+1])]) for i in range(len(list_1))]
```